# problem with fireStateChanged() method for JSpinner

Tags: java, events, swing

I have a problem invoking the fireStateChanged() method for a JSpinner. I create a JSpinner and when I try to invoke fireStateChanged() method for that spinner `someSpinner.fireStateChanged();`, eclipse shows me this error:

> The method fireStateChanged() from the type JSpinner is not visible

Does anyone have any idea on how to correctly invoke fireStateChanged() method for a JSpinner in my case?

Thanx =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the method is protected. This means the method can only be called from within the JSpinner class or a subclass (or a class in the same package). It's not supposed to be called from the outside.

The spinner is responsible for firing a state changed event each time a change to its model occurs. Change the value of the spinner, either through the UI or by calling the setValue method, and a state changed event will automatically be fired by the spinner.